# How can I create Gantt Chart - Why I couldnt see series group in my report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have these data.

[image]

I just want to see the planned order per line per day
so lets say the report is 1 day
1 day is 7u30 till 23h
so in there we will see what is planned for the day

my script is like this:

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[LREP_PLANNING_PER_DAY]    Script Date: 8/3/2017 2:48:56 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

-- =============================================
-- Description: <Return The get Selections for Reports ,,>
-- =============================================
/*


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LREP_PLANNING_PER_DAY]


        @DATE AS DATETIME

AS
*/
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON

/* TESTING
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2017-05-09'
*/


SELECT 
STR_ORDER_ID
,DT_ESTIMATED_STARTTIME_UTC
,DT_ESTIMATED_ENDTIME_UTC
,STR_EQUIPMENT_LABEL
FROM [dbo].[lFp_Orders] 
WHERE STR_ORDER_STATUS='Planned'
AND  (DT_ESTIMATED_STARTTIME_UTC between @DATE + '07:30:00' and @DATE + '23:00:00')

END`
```

I did my report design like this:

[image]

but in preview I couldn't see my order. Can you help me this issue?

[image]

I want to see my all order for line in one day.
but my order interval must be depend on between end time and start time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself and If you have a problem with gantt chart you can create bar chart after that you can change chart type. I fixed my issue like this.